# Name of colour of paint on Kink Volte BMX

Tags: frames, repair, bmx, paint

I am looking for the color name for restoration on my kink volte?

serial # aca10e001651

Any ideas would help. I'm hitting a brick wall with google.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly serial numbers are useless - they're not a VIN like cars have and only mean something to the manufacturer, who may have encoded info in the number, or may not even have kept track of the numbers.

1. If you have a sample of the paint you want, take it to an automotive paint specialist and ask for a colour match.  Not your local big-box store, somewhere that just does car paint.  Explain what you're painting, and whether the sample is fresh or faded, which will give the mixers extra info.   You can generally get the paint installed in a spray can.

2. If you don't have a sample, try and get a good photo of a suitable bike.  Ideally a photo taken in sunlight would help.

3. Don't bother matching colours.  Just pick a shade that you like and go from there.  Consider what decals you have and get a contrasting or tonal matching colour for the labels.

Either way - get clear coats as well to protect the paint and decals/stickers.

4. Try a powder coating company - this is a baked on plastic-like finish that is super hard wearing.  You may be limited in the colour selection to the powders that are on hand.  This stuff doesn't need a clear coat, but you will have to clean and prep the frame perfectly including blocking all machined surfaces and threads etc.

5. Try contacting Kink directly at  https://kinkbmx.com/  though this may get ignored.  Doesn't hurt to try.

Your bike is your bike, build it how you want it to be.

Comment: I don't specialize in paint, but my impression is that sometimes, the type of base coat can modify the final color. If the OP is very concerned about a precise color match, this will be important to account for (and it would be a good reason to send the frame to a professional). If Kink responds, they may be able to provide a paint code (I think these tend to be specific to paint suppliers).